# Jquery animation ignore .stop

Tags: jquery

I have two separate scripts that both control the same element. The trouble is, the second script uses `.stop` when the user scrolls. The first script makes a div element scroll down from the top of the page by 50 pixels in 1 second. If the user scrolls before that one second is up, the div box won't scroll all the way down.

Is there a way to prevent this piece of code responding to `.stop` or perhaps another way to write it without using animations?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.undermenu').animate({'margin-top': '52px'}, 1000);
});
```

Piece of code with the `.stop` that is causing the first one not to work when a user scrolls:

```
var previousScrollTop = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 60) {
       if(previousScrollTop <= 60) {
            $("li.um").fadeOut(300);
            $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({width:'160px'}, { duration: 500, queue: true});
            $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'60px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('li.um').html('12345678901 pete@rufusmusic.co.uk');
            }, 400);
            $("li.um").fadeIn(1000);
            $( "ul.undermenu" ).addClass( "border" );
        }
     } else if (previousScrollTop > 60) {
        $("li.um").fadeOut(300);
        $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({height:'22px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
        $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:viewportWidth}, { duration: 500,  queue: true});
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('li.um').html('Email: pete@rufusmusic.co.uk | Call: 12345678901 | Call: 01290923876');
          }, 400);
        $("li.um").fadeIn(1000);
        $( "ul.undermenu" ).removeClass( "border" );
     }
     previousScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: Where is the first script?

Comment: The first script is the the three line piece of code in the question. It makes the div scroll down 52px from the top, using .animation. But the second script, the longer one I just added to the question, has a .stop which stops the first animation running. So is there a way I can make the first, shorter script ignore .stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    animationFnished = false;  // initialise the state of the animation
    $('ul.undermenu').animate({'margin-top': '52px'}, 1000, function(){
        animationFinished = true; // update the state after the animation is done
    });
});
```

Then in the second script

```
var previousScrollTop = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width(),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 60) {
       if(previousScrollTop <= 60) {
            $("li.um").fadeOut(300);

            if(animationFinished) // we are done with the margin animation
                $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({width:'160px'}, { duration: 500, queue: true});
            else // animation is still going on or has not started yet
                $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:'160px'}, { duration: 500, queue: true});

            $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'60px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
            window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('li.um').html('12345678901 pete@rufusmusic.co.uk');
            }, 400);
            $("li.um").fadeIn(1000);
            $( "ul.undermenu" ).addClass( "border" );
        }
     } else if (previousScrollTop > 60) {
        $("li.um").fadeOut(300);

        if(animationFinished)  // we are done with the margin animation
            $("ul.undermenu").stop(true, false).animate({height:'22px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});
        else  // animation is still going on or has not started yet
            $("ul.undermenu").animate({height:'22px'}, { duration: 200, queue: true});

        $("ul.undermenu").animate({width:viewportWidth}, { duration: 500,  queue: true});
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('li.um').html('Email: pete@rufusmusic.co.uk | Call: 12345678901 | Call: 01290923876');
          }, 400);
        $("li.um").fadeIn(1000);
        $( "ul.undermenu" ).removeClass( "border" );
     }
     previousScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

In this we are initialising a variable which is set to `true` or `false` depending on the current state of the `margin animation`. Then when the user scrolls, this variable is checked and accordingly the correct statement is run.